# Вопросы по поводу inline (встраивания) геттеров

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я пытался разобраться со встраиванием сам, но не особо уверен в некоторых деталях.
Насколько я понял встраивание происходит автоматически, и никаких дополнительных ключевых слов для этого не надо.

1. Как конкретно встраиваются геттеры? допустим есть геттер:
   `int getSize() const noexcept { return _size; }`
   где _size переменная типа int, объявлённая в классе, с этим геттером.
   что выдаст компилятор при вызове геттера: `obj.getSize();`?
   этот код просто заменится на `obj._size;`?
2. Встраиваются ли функции из статических библиотек?
3. Встраиваются ли методы шаблонных классов?
4. Не повредит ли скорости работы программы использование геттеров в методах того же класса, где определены эти самые геттеры. (иногда это просто улучшает читаемость)

Ps. компилятор - Visual c++ самой последней версии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Все функции встраиваются одинаково. Никаких особенностей именно для "геттеров" нет. На уровне языка вопроса "как встраиваются функции" не существует, ибо такое встраивание ни в чем не проявляется. А все остальное - детали реализации. Да, вполне возможно, что код просто заменится на `obj._size`.

   Однако буквальный код `obj.getSize();` обычно будет удален вообще, ибо побочных эффектов у функции нет, а результат вызова никак не используется.
2. Встраиваться могут только функции, чьи определения целиком и полностью видны в точке их вызова во время компиляции. Так что "статические библиотеки" тут вообще ни при чем. Встраиваемые функции по этой причине определяются в заголовочных файлах. А с каким типом библиотеки идет этот заголовочный файл - никакого значения не имеет.
3. Шаблонность класса никак не влияет на встраиваемость методов. Это совершенно ортогональные вопросы.

   В то же время шаблонность может побочно помогать встраиваемости, ибо шаблоны обычно целиком определяются в заголовочных файлах.
4. Не повредит. А дальше: пробуйте и смотрите.